# Merging two JQuery animations

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am working on a `JQuery` animation and I hope I can get help from the community.

### Objective

I am trying to create an animation of the globe. The globe starts to appear from the **left** and then starts to **bounce**. While bouncing, it also moves in **forward** direction towards to **right**. When it reaches the **centre** of the page, it stops.
After that the next animation starts. In the next animation, the globe starts to **rotate**.

### What have I tried?

I have both of the animations working properly as **single units** but I am having trouble joining them into one.
I am done with the bouncing part but while the globe is bouncing, the rotating effect should be hidden and should start after the bounce effect is over.

I tried using `hide()` function with delay to do that but I am unable to make it work. I would be very thankful for the help.
[Here](http://apptec.net/5.html) is what I have implemented until now.

Please help me to hide the rotating animation **until** the bounce is over.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not clear why you are bouncing the ball if you want to hide it anyway. If you want to hide the ball, don't bounce it... problem solved.

Comment: @RegisteredUser: There are two balls. Which would be displayed as one to the user.

Comment: So which one you want to hide. You say that both animations are running, but I see only the bouncing one. Why is there a globe in the center with buttons on it?

Comment: The globe in the center is the second animation. I want to hide it until the bouncing ball comes exactly at the same location and then display it on the bouncing ball.

Comment: I am having trouble saving and running your page locally. Post a link to a zip folder if you can

Comment: @RegisteredUser: Here it is: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B7z7rCJy9WnKcHBwUkJhd1pmNWs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $zombie = $('img#flickr');
          function runit(){
            $("#main_content").hide();
            $zombie
             .animate({ opacity: 1 },"fast")

             .animate({top:'500px',left:'100px'}, {duration:500})
             .animate({top:'0px', left:'180px'}, {duration:600})
             .animate({top:'400px', left:'180px'}, {duration:700})
             .animate({top:'0px', left:'260px'}, {duration:800})
             .animate({top:'300px', left:'320px'}, {duration:900})
             .animate({top:'50px', left:'360px'}, {duration:1000})
             .animate({top:'200px', left:'420px'}, {duration:1100})
             .animate({top:'80px', left:'460px'}, {duration:1200})
             .animate({top:'150px', left:'480px'}, {duration:1200})          
             .animate({top:'104px', left:'495px'}, 1300,function(){
                   $("#main_content").show();
                });
          }
        runit()
</script>
```